# How to use JSTL within JSP declaration

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, scriptlet

I want to use JSTL within JSP declaration. I have code like:

```
<%! void fetchData(String .., String ..){
    //some code...
    pageContext.setAttribute("test",valueForJSTL); // Wont work until I pass pageContext from calling scriptlet
    //some code...
%><%
    //use pageContext variable set above to user in JSP (c:out, wcf:getData etc)**
%><%
}%>
```

I wonder why is it not allowed to used scriptlet (line 5-7) within JSP declaration. Or is there any other way to handle this?

I am calling above function from a scriptlet and I want this method to do some manipulation, add a variable in pageContext/request and fetch the variable in JSTL to fetch the data from DB .

You can find complete file at:
http://wikisend.com/download/738986/MyView.jsp
The JSTL within declaration "fetchCatalogEntries" is not working.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please show us your actual JSP, rather than fragments of syntax.

Comment: Hi,

Please find the file at:
http://wikisend.com/download/738986/MyView.jsp

at line 46 I am calling the declaration. Within "fetchCatalogEntries" function I want to use JSTL at line 88. However it's not allowing to do so. I not sure if we can use scriptlet tags within a declaration method.

Comment: Sorry, but you have done nearly everything, that you must not do in JSP file, kindly go through some tutorials, e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/

Comment: You cannot do this. Please advise on the context. If you have written this code then see the comment above. If this is some legacy app then an alternative approach will be required.

Comment: Hi @Alan
I Know lots of logic gone into the JSP. Reason bean there is no support from OOB to get these details in JAVA. That's why I have to use the JSP.

The only detail which I wanted to know is why in JSP Declaration, pageContext or request variables are not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the generated code for the scriptlet <% %>goes in the service method which is like called again and over the same object using multiple request threads

Whereas <%!, goes into the global class space or simply to declare methods and variables global for a JSP page.

Hence in your scriptlet you can call the method say fetchData() or any other like you would inside a service() method like in a normal java class.

You can even declare a field as below and refer it as in the example below :

```
<%!
    private final Logger logger = new Logger(this.getClass());
    private UserService userService = null;
    public void jspInit() {
        userService = new UserService();
    }
    private String getUserStatus(String userID) {
        return userServce.getUserStatus(userID);
    }
%>

<%
    String userID = request.getParameter("userid");
    String userStatus = getUserStatus(userID);
%>
```

Finally I would recommend you to NOT use scriptlets and use JSTL tags and libraries like the core-tag-libs and many others, these will help you in the long term.